# JQuery UI ! Draggable image and revertion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, droppable

I have 4 droppable blocks and 1 draggable image, how to achive effect of revertion, only if the I dropped my image not into droppable element?
I used this options, but can't reach wished result:

```
$('.myimage').draggable({
   scope: "tasks",
   revert: true,
   revertDuration: 1,
   stop: function(event, ui) {    }
  });

  $('.keeper').droppable({
     accept: ".card",
     scope: "tasks",
     tolerance: "fit",
     greedy: true,
     drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("background-color","green");
        //$('.card').draggable({ scope: "tasks", revert: false });
       }
   });
```

so as you can see the revert set to "true", and when I dropped image not into .keeper, I have the revertion effect, and it's works fine untill I'm not drop .myimage to .keeper, after that I can dropping .myimage to everywhere on the page (revert doesn't work anymore), but I'm still need that .myimage was with this feature as for non-.keeper class elements, I hope you understand what I want.